# Why does my string line show an error in this program?

Tags: java

Consider:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d=scan.nextDouble();
        String s=scan.nextLine();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

In the string part, I tried writing a sentence. But instead of printing the whole sentence, it just printed the first word of the sentence.

Comment: Please show exactly how you are typing in the information.  All on one line, on multiple lines, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't seems to be like throwing error. You might be getting blank data as you are feeding directly from the commandline, as soon as you press enter after giving the double value this will pick the enter. I tried your code and it is feeding properly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        String s=scan.nextLine();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1\bin\java.exe" "
-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=59893:
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1\bin" 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\codebase\Spring\Task\untitled\out\production\untitled Test
26
35.64 my name is 


String:  my name is 
Double: 35.64
Int: 26
```